# view render in zend not working properly as expected

Tags: zend-framework

My zend layout and scripts are detecting fine. but when in init function of my IndexController I write $this->view->render("header.phtml") It does not show anything one the screen, whereas when I write echo ($this->view->render("header.phtml"); it displays my header.phtml file. Here is my IndexController

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

```
public function init()
{
    $layout = $this->_helper->layout();
    //$this->view = $this->getResource('View');
    echo ($this->view->render("header.phtml"));
        //echo"<pre>";
        //var_dump($this->view);
        //var_dump(APPICATION_PATH);
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
    echo "In default index con";
}
```

}

Also when Igive my url to/mypath/index It does not display the simple line "I'm in index controller" which I'm just echoing. In my bootstrap here is my Zend_Layout settings.

```
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_View');
$this->view = new Zend_View();
$this->view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
$this->view->setScriptPath($this->root .'/application/default/views/scripts');
    $viewRenderer=new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
     // Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
     // $view->setScriptPath($this->root.'/'.$theme.'/views/scripts/');
     //$view->setScriptPath($this->root.'/application/default/views/scripts/');
     $this->view->addScriptPath($this->root.'/application/admin/views/scripts');
     $this->view->addScriptPath($this->root.'/application/business/views/scripts');
    // $this->view->setHelperPath($this->root .'/application/default/views/helpers');
     $this->layout = Zend_Layout::startMvc(
        array(
                'layoutPath' => $this->root . '/application/default/views/'.$crt_theme.'/layouts',
                'layout' => 'layout'
                )
                );
        $this->registry->set("theme", $crt_theme);
```

variable $crt_theme is set to 'default'.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do.  The `render()` method is supposed to return the rendered HTML not display it. If you are looking for a way to layout templates in Zend you might want to take a look at Zend_Layout for how to properly do it.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render()` is working as intended; it returns a string that you should then `echo`.

It is very unusual to be rendering directly in a controller however. At a minimum, you should be rendering your header and footer from `views/scripts/index/index.phtml`, though using [`Zend_Layout`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html) would be even better. If you are using `Zend_Application`, then you can start using `Zend_Layout` simply by adding:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

to your `application/config/application.ini` file. You then need to create a `application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml` file which could look something like this:

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
$this->headTitle('My website');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?> 
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <!-- Other <head> elements and view helpers here -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Rob' answer is correct although you may need some more information as you appear to be working hard at making this complicated.
 ZF when used as an MVC has a place to put layouts and defaults for using them.

If you are using the Zend_Tool command line interface start with the commmand: `zf enable layout` and the tool will add the default directory and a default *layout.phtml* to your project.
in the *application.ini* it will add the line:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

and at that path it will add the file `layout.phtml`
If you need to change the name of the default layout add this line with the name of your script without the .phtml

```
resources.layout.layout = master
```

There are as many ways as you can think of to use this file, but here is an example of how I use it.
I like to set my project defaults in my *application.ini* file so if I need to change anything it's easy.

```
View Settings
;*************
resources.view[]=
resources.view.charset = "UTF-8"
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
resources.view.language = "en"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

then in my bootstrap I setup the view I want use, I do it here so that if I have multiple layouts (i usually do) it's easy to change css or js files in one place.

```
protected function _initView() {
        //Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();

        $view->addHelperPath('/../library/Application/View/Helper');

        $view->doctype(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->view->doctype);

        $view->headTitle('Our Home');

        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', Zend_Registry::get(
                        'config')->resources->view->contentType);
        $view->headLink()->setStylesheet('/css/normalize.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/liquid.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/typography.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet(
                '/javascript/mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/nav.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/table.css');

        //add javascript files
        $view->headScript()->setFile('/javascript/mediaelement/build/jquery.js');
        $view->headScript()->appendFile('/javascript/modernizr.js');

        //add it to the view renderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                        'ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        //Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }
```

Notice all of those headLink(), headScript() and docType() entries, these are where the data is set for [placeholders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial), that will be used in the layout.

Now the layout, the actual content from your other action based scripts will typically be rendered by the placeholder `$this->layout()->content`

```
<?php
echo $this->doctype() . "\n";//placeholder
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta() . "\n" ?><!-- displays all meta data passed -->
        <?php echo $this->headLink() . "\n" ?><!-- displays all links passed -->
        <?php echo $this->headscript(). "\n"?><!-- displays all scripts passed -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="container">
            <header class="block">
                <hgroup id="header" class ="column span-24">
                    <h1>Our Home</h1>
                </hgroup>
                <nav>
                    <div id="nav" class="column span-24">
                        <?php echo $this->layout()->nav ?>&nbsp;<!-- Custom Placeholder -->
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <section class="block">
                <div id="main" class="column span-18 border">
                    <div id="flash">
                        <?php
                        //flash messenger display location
                        if (count($this->messages) > 0) {
                            printf("<h3 id='flash'>%s</h3>", $this->messages[0]);
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?><!-- Default placeholder, where views are rendered -->
                </div>
                <aside id="sidebar" class="column span-4 last">
                    <?php echo $this->layout()->search ?><!-- Custom placeholder -->
                    <div id="subNav">
                        <?php echo $this->layout()->subNav ?>&nbsp;<!-- Custom placeholder -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="adminMenu">
                        <h4>Administration Links</h4>
                        <?php echo $this->layout()->adminMenu ?>&nbsp;<!-- Custom placeholder -->
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </section>
            <footer class="block">
                <div id="footer" class="column span-24">
                    <p>Created with <a href="http://framework.zend.com/">Zend Framework. &COPY; </a></p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </section>
        <?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?><!-- placeholder -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

**[Edit]**
One more thing, this always seems to be the next question. *"How do I change my layout from the default in my controller/action?"*

to change the layout from your controller you would typically do it with a preDispatch() method and just pass the name of your new layout to the layout helper.

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('myOtherLayout');
```

doing just this will change the layout for every action in the controller. To be more selective you can use a conditional, like:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'player') {
            $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('player');//reset layout
            //add 2 new headscripts
            $this->view->headScript()->appendFile(
                    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js'
                    );
            $this->view->headScript()->appendFile(
                    '/javascript/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js'
                    );
        }
```